# Knapsack with mutually exclusive items

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

While standard knapsack problem can be solved by dynamic programming, I am trying to twist the problem a bit to clear my concept, however I found it maybe harder than I thought.

Original knapsack problem is that given a knapsack with size `W`, and a list of items which weight `w[i]` and has a value `v[i]`, find the subset of items which can fit in the knapsack with highest total value.

To my understanding, this can be done by `O(Wn)` with dynamic programming, where `n` is the number of items.

---

Now if I try to add `m` constrains, each of them is a pair of items which can only be picked mutual exclusively (i.e. if there exist a constrain of item A and item B, then I can only take either one of them but not both)

Under such constrains, can this problem still be solved by dynamic programming in `O(Wn)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Assumption**: Each element is included in atmost one constraint.

For the usual Knapsack problem, the optimal substructure that the problem exhibits is as follows:

For each item there can be two cases:
1. The item is included in the solution
2. The item not included in the solution.

Hence, the optimal solution for `n` items is given by max of following two values.
1. Maximum value obtained by `n-1` items and `W` weight.
2. `v_n` + maximum value obtained by `n-1` items and `W-w_n` weight.

Now if we add the constraint that either of `n`th or `(n-1)`th item can exist in the solution, then the optimal solution for `n` items is given by max of following three values.
1. Maximum value obtained by `n-2` items and `W` weight.
2. `v_n` + maximum value obtained by `n-2` items and `W-w_n` weight.
3. `v_(n-1)` + maximum value obtained by `n-2` items and `W-w_(n-1)` weight.

So we treat each pair of elements in the constraint as a single element and execute the dynamic programming algorithm in `O(Wn)` time.

Comment: Still digesting but sounds very valid to me...just to clear my mind, does that mean if each constrain is not a pair, but a set of items, which each item within must be mutually exclusive, that still can be used similar algorithm which has O(Wn) time?

Comment: @shole So long as the constraints are not overlapping (no item is present in more than one constraint), this approach can be extended to multiple items in the constraints.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement a simple code using this concept, will accept it ASAP once I finished it...

Comment: I face a bit difficulty when implementing a case that ALL elements are included in some constrain...the recurrence formula is a bit confusing, but I believe it is the correct direction, thanks :)